# Scanf in functions repeats input request twice

Tags: c, function, scanf

```
//Main Function of Calculator Project
int main (void)
{
        int input, result, result1, result2, result3, result4;

        printf ("===================================\n");
        printf ( "WELCOME TO THE CALCULATOR PROJECT\n");
        printf ("===================================\n\n");

        printf ("Option 1. ADDITION\n");
        printf ("Option 2. SUBTRACTION\n");
        printf ("Option 3. MULTIPLICATION\n");
        printf ("Option 4. DIVISION\n\n");

        printf ("Enter Option:>> ");
        scanf  ("%d", &input);

        switch (input)
        {
                case 1:
                        addition(result1);
                        printf ("Result: %d\n", addition(result1));
                        break;
                case 2:
                        subtraction(result2);
                        printf ("Result: %d\n", subtraction(result2));
                        break;
                case 3:
                        multiplication(result3);
                        printf ("Result: %d\n", multiplication(result3));
                        break;
                case 4:
                        division(result4);
                        printf ("Result: %d\n", division(result1));
                        break;
                default:
                        printf ("Invalid Input\n");
 }
           return 0;

}
```

When ever the program runs it return the correct calculations however always asks for the input twice no matter what user function runs.

Comment: please do not make `return`  statement look like a function, please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question

Comment: Im trying to learn by writing a calculator project involving functions and a switch. However when a user function runs it request the input twice and then returns the input to main?

Comment: Can share your main function too ?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the functions that ask for input and perform the calculation twice:

```
case 1:
    addition(result1); // You first call it here
    printf ("Result: %d\n", addition(result1)); // You call it again here
    break;
```

You're also passing an uninitialized variable as the argument. That variable should be used to hold the return value, not as an argument.

So you call it once, assign the result to a variable, then print that variable.

```
int result = -1;
case 1:
    result = addition();
    break;
case 2:
    result = subtraction();
    break;
case 3:
    result = multiplication();
    break;
case 4:
    result = division();
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid input\n");
}
printf("Result: %d\n", result);
```